# Damped harmonic oscillation (LC circuit)

Tags: electric-circuits, oscillators, dissipation

The $LC$ circuit I'm considering contains a capacitor, an inductor and an electrical resistance. There is no battery: intially the capacitor has a charge $Q$ and the electric current in the circuit is zero. I know the equation that describes this circuit is $$q'' + \frac{R}{L}q' + \omega^{2}  q = 0$$ with $\omega = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$ and where $q(t)$ gives the electrical charge in the capacitor.

I know this equation has three possible solutions depending on the sign of $$\Delta = \frac{R^{2}}{L^{2}}-4\omega ^{2},$$ more spefically we could have overdamped, critically-damped and underdamped oscillation.

While playing around with the graphs, I noticed almost no difference between the overdamped and critically-damped oscillation, because the graphs approach so quickly zero that it is very hard to distinguish them from the axis.

Can you give me three sample function, one for each case, so that I can plot them and be able to clearly see their behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a difference between the overdamped and critically damped cases in the form of their solutions, the reason one doesn't usually see it is because of the choice of initial conditions. Of course, the differences will be more evident close to $t=0$, as far away both these solutions attain the equilibrium position. It's just that the critically damped case attains it the *fastest*.

You can write the differential equation for the LCR system as $$\ddot{q} + \gamma \dot{q} + \omega_0^2 q = 0,$$

where $\omega_0 = 1/\sqrt{LC}$ and $\gamma = R/L$. To solve this equation, we "guess" a solution of the form $e^{\alpha t}$. Substituting this into the equation, our differential equation just becomes an algebraic equation in $\alpha$: $$\alpha^2 + \gamma \alpha + \omega_0^2 = 0,$$

whose solutions are $$\alpha= -\frac{\gamma}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{\gamma^2}{2} - \omega_0^2}.$$

In other words, there are in general two values of $\alpha$ that can satisfy the differential equation, and we're happy since this is a second order differential equation and we'd expect two linearly independent solutions. Of course, we are interested in *oscillatory* solutions, and these look like exponentials! The trick is to realise that complex exponentials are oscillatory solutions and so we define

$$\omega = \sqrt{\omega_0^2 - \frac{\gamma^2}{4}}$$ as the new "oscillating frequency" of our solutions, so that when $\gamma\to 0$, $\omega \to \omega_0$, and we get the solutions to be

$$q_1(t) \propto e^{-(\gamma/2)t}e^{i\omega t} \quad \quad q_2(t) \propto e^{-(\gamma/2)t}e^{-i\omega t},$$

and so we have two oscillatory solutions **provided that the quantity $\omega$ is real,** which will happen whenever $\omega_0^2 > \frac{\gamma^2}{4},$ which is the condition for the "underdamped" oscillator. When $\omega_0^2 < \frac{\gamma^2}{4},$ however, our solutions don't oscillate! We have two exponentially decaying solutions, which we can get by simply setting $\omega \to -\omega$ in our earlier solutions. This is the overdamped case.

But what about the case $\omega_0 = \frac{\gamma}{4}$? Well, you might be tempted to lump this in with the "overdamped" case, since the solutions "look" exponential, but there's a problem. If you notice, when $\omega_0 = \gamma/4$, this means $\omega = 0$, or in other words our two solutions above $q_1(t)$ and $q_2(t)$ are identical! We no longer have two linearly independent solutions to a second order linear differential equation! But this isn't possible, there *must* be another solution that we're missing.

It turns out there is, the second linearly independent solution is $$q_2(t) \propto t e^{-(\gamma/2)t}.$$

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to show that this function *is* a solution to the differential equation above **provided** $\omega_0 = \gamma/4$, but *isn't* a solution in either of the other cases. So to conclude, the general solutions are:

**Underdamped Oscillator:** ($\omega_0^2 > \gamma/4$)

$$q(t) = e^{-(\gamma/2) t} \left(A_1 e^{i \omega t} + A_2 e^{-i \omega t}\right)$$

**Overdamped Oscillator:** ($\omega_0^2 < \gamma/4$)

$$q(t) = e^{-(\gamma/2) t} \left(A_1 e^{-\omega t} + A_2 e^{\omega t}\right)$$

**Critically Damped Oscillator:** ($\omega_0^2 = \gamma/4$)

$$q(t) = e^{-(\gamma/2) t} \left(A_1 + A_2 t\right)$$

The different constants $A_1$ and $A_2$ can be set using the initial conditions, and you can easily find cases where the critically damped and overdamped cases give noticeably different behaviour, depending on the initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real visible difference between the critically damped and the over-damped case.

See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda2.html

Comment: But shouldn't critical-damping provide a smoother effect than overdamping, since $R$ is lower in the first case?